# How can I change a color of Material UI GridActionsCellItem icon button using a theme?

Tags: material-ui

I have an action button in a data grid (pro):

```
<GridActionsCellItem icon={ <EditIcon/> } />
```

how can I put `color="inhereted"` or `color="#123"` to all my action icon buttons using a theme?

I want to make all my action icon buttons to default to the same color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the change in your `theme` the code below should work for you.

```
    MuiDataGrid: {
      root: {
        '& .MuiDataGrid-actionsCell': {
          '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
            color: 'red'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Or you can use styled components like this

```
const GridActionsCellItemStyled = styled(GridActionsCellItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
    color: "red"
  }
}));

<GridActionsCellItemStyled
  icon={<EditIcon />}
  label="Edit"
/>,
```